# React Chartjs 2 display axes above datasets backgroundColor

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

I have a Line Chart with *chart.js* and one of the lines has to fill the background delimited with another line. It works well, but how can I do it to see chart axes when the background is filled ??

Here is an example of what I currently have: [codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/chart-line-axes-m0cth?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From playing around with it, most of your options are not being recognized at all.

I played with the colors, layouts, displaying things, etc., and nothing made a difference.  The only thing that's making a difference is the `responsive` key.

Normally, the way you would change the way the lines would be displayed is like this:

```js
const options = {
  legend: { display: false },
  title: { display: true, text: "Line Chart" },
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
        z: 99
      },
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }]
  },
  xAxes: [{
    gridLines: {
        z: 99
    }
  }],
  responsive: true
};
```

In your `options` object, under the scales key, under each axis, you can set the z-index of the gridlines.  This set of options should work, according to [this](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/axes/styling.html).

However, because your options aren't being recognized, none of the options here are even taking effect in the first place.

I haven't used Chart.js in react so I can't really help you more than that, in this aspect.

However, what I can say does work, is in line 10 in your sample code in the sandbox, I changed the hex value to rgba:
`backgroundColor: "rgba(235, 245, 251, 0.5)",`

It's the same color, only a little lighter, but what is most important is you can see the grid lines.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ7v3.png

My advice is if you're only using React for this chart, don't.  It seems to be making things harder.

Comment: It works well with ```gridLines: { z: 99 }```. The options weren't recognized because I was using chartjs v2.9 in my web aplication but in the codesandbox example it had chartjs v3. Now It is updated.